# Multiple Users views for signup in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to create two different signup pages. So from my home view I created these buttons:

```
<% if not logged_in? %>
  <%= link_to "I'm a Hero", signup_path, class: "btn btn-lg btn-primary" %>
  <%= link_to "I'm a villain", villain_path, class: "btn btn-lg btn-primary" %>

<% end %>
```

Now the route obviously looks like this for the "I'm a Hero" button:

```
  get 'signup'  => 'users#new'
```

I can render a nice signup form in views -> user -> new.html.erb. I was thinking that I can do the same for my "I'm a villain" button.

First I wanted to create a new file views -> user -> villain.html.erb. Then I wanted to create a route like this:

```
  get 'villain'  => 'users#villain'
```

If I now click on my "I'm a villain" button, basically nothing happens. And as for localhost:3000/villain, I get redirected to localhost:3000.

What did I miss?

This is the server log when clicking on "Im a villain"

```
Started GET "/villain" for 130.75.71.234 at 2017-03-11 14:07:00 +0000
Cannot render console from 130.75.71.234! Allowed networks: 127.0.0.1, ::1,     127.0.0.0/127.255.255.255
Processing by UsersController#villain as HTML
User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" IS NULL  LIMIT 1
Redirected to https://ruby-project.c9users.io/
Completed 302 Found in 601ms (ActiveRecord: 1.5ms)


Started GET "/" for 130.75.71.234 at 2017-03-11 14:07:01 +0000
Cannot render console from 130.75.71.234! Allowed networks: 127.0.0.1, ::1,   127.0.0.0/127.255.255.255
Processing by StaticPagesController#home as HTML
User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" IS NULL   LIMIT 1
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" IS NULL LIMIT 1
Rendered static_pages/home.html.erb within layouts/application (4.6ms)
Rendered layouts/_shim.html.erb (0.5ms)
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" IS NULL LIMIT 1
Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (2.0ms)
Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (0.8ms)
Completed 200 OK in 386ms (Views: 381.7ms | ActiveRecord: 0.5ms)
```

Comment: Can you post the server log generated on clicking "I'm aVillain"?

Comment: @Pavan updated the question ;)

Comment: `Redirected to https://ruby-project.c9users.io/` feels suspicious to me.

Comment: @Pavan that is basically my localhost:3000 since I'm working on c9.io which is a cloudbased environment. the real link contains my user name as well but I chose not to display it here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define the "villain" action in the controller. You probably have the "new" action already defined because you created it through the generator. That is probably why the "new" action does work and not the "villain" one.